# Search items in checklistbox using text entered in textbox

Tags: javascript, dom

I want search inside checklist box. When user enters text in a text field then if such item exists in checkbox list, it should be selected.

HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged= "return SearchList();"/>
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Vincent</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Jennifer</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Shynne</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Christian</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Helen</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Vladi</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Vinz</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Churchill</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Rod</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Mark</asp:ListItem>
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

JavaScript:

```
function SearchList() {
    try {
        var l = document.getElementById('<%= CheckBoxList1.ClientID %>');
        var tb = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
        var p = l.item.length
        if (tb.value == "") {
            ClearSelection(l);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < l.options.length; i++) {
                if (l.options[i].value.toLowerCase().match(tb.value.toLowerCase())) {
                    l.options[i].selected = true;
                    return false;
                } else {
                    ClearSelection(l);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {}
}

function ClearSelection(lb) {
    lb.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: its very urgent !!  help me!!

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: You have to explain what's wrong with your code and post it in order for use to help you. You haven't even asked a proper question! And regarding *"its very urgent !! help me!!"*: If it's urgent, pay someone. We are all volunteers and we will help you as it fits in our own schedule. If you expect someone to code a complete solution for you, just based on a description of what you "want", then this is the wrong site anyway.

Comment: If you want to provide additional information, please [**edit** your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15945174/edit). And make sure to read the "How to Format" box on the right side to format your code properly.

Comment: above is my code simple text box (to enter item) and checklistbox@SJnawali

Comment: sir i just stuck on java script function.To search in checklistboxlist

Comment: posted whole code now you can help me

Comment: You explained what you want to achieve. You posted your code. So far so good (thanks for the update)! However you haven't explained yet what the *problem* really is. We don't even know where to start looking... Is your code not working how you expect it to? If yes, then what exactly happens? Do you get any error? Did you do some [basic debugging](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners)? Then there are still some things unclear, for example, when and how is `SearchList` called? You should print out the error in the `catch` statement, in case there is a problem.

Comment: The more effort you are putting into your question (information, code formatting, etc), the easier you make it for us to help you and the better help you will get (since we will put more effort into our answers as well).

Comment: ontextchange of textbox  SearchListis called (sorry for not putting)       OnTextChanged= "return SearchList();". and problem in I am not able to cpmpare text from textbox and items from checklistbox. and then focus on that particular item

Comment: Remove the `var p = l.item.length` line and see if it works then.

Comment: @FelixKling i have edited it again and also put the problem

Comment: @FelixKling problem is with when I am comparing checklist item and text enter in text box  at this point it is through exception"undefine".

Comment: @user2269583 I don't know about ASP and ListItem also, the demo about Select as like ListItem can be helpful for u...If u like

Comment: @SJnawali plz give it

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about **asp**, and I m going to figure out in simple HTML
It might be helpful for you.
**HTML Portion**

```
<select id="combo">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" id="searchTXT" onblur="checkCombo();">
```

**Javascript Portion**

```
function checkCombo() {
    try{
        var searchVal = $('#searchTXT').val();
        var options= document.getElementById('combo').options;
        for (var i= 0, n= options.length; i < n ; i++) {
        if (options[i].value.toLowerCase()==searchVal.toLowerCase()) {
            document.getElementById("combo").selectedIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    }
    catch(e){}
    }
```

Comment: You seem to use jQuery, but the OP does not mention jQuery at all. You should at least mention that you are using jQuery and explain what it is. Even better: Provide a solution without jQuery.

Comment: @Felix Kling, Thank you for valuable information...I think user know the JQuery by observing the code...I will try in next time...